# Using delprof in command prompt remotly. Which user will it be run as if no user is specified?

Tags: remote, user-accounts

If i use delprof2 and cmd to remotly delete profiles, which user would this be run under if no other user is given?

Many thanks

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run something as yourself and try connect to a remote computer, Windows will normally use your account permissions. The two common ways around this are if the program has a place to give specific login details then do that, or for you to run the program as another account using Run As.

I expect delprof2 is no exception, but I haven't used it.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that if i give the technician user that we will be using the correct privilidge then it should run?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but I don't know what those would be; from reading about it, it can edit system level registry entries as part of the delete, as well as clearing the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

As TessellatingHeckler stated in his answer, a Windows application runs under the context of the user who launches the application, unless configured otherwise via credentials options in the application, or by using Run As.

Note that I'm not referring to system components, services, or web applications here, I'm only referring to applications launched interactively by a user.